# BigQuery cannot add data with nodejs API

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-api-nodejs-client

I tried to use google-cloud-functions with BigQuery using the following cloud function example [link](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/bigquery-import/functions/index.js).
I didn't have any errors but the data didn't add to BigQuery.

BigQuery response is (status 200):

> [   {
>       "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse"   } ]

I tested locally using expressjs app with google service account but I got the same response.

Here is my code use in local:

```
    function saveLogBigQuery(req, res, status, errors=null){  
 const dataset = bigquery.dataset('logs_functions');  
 const table = dataset.table('testing');

      return table.insert([{
        name:'works!'   }]).then(function(data) {
        console.log("works!");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
        res.send(data);   })
        .catch(function(err) {
          // An API error or partial failure occurred.
          console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
          res.send(err);
        }); }
       router2.get('/places', (req, res) => {   return saveLogBigQuery(req,res,200); });
       router2.listen(3000, function () {   console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!') });
```

And here is my local config:

```
const bigquery = require('@google-cloud/bigquery')({
  projectId: 'project-id',
  credentials: require('./service-account.json')
});
```

Any ideas, what is wrong?

**EDIT:**

*RESPONSE:* Probably was something with cache or refresh of page https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/project-id , now was the data :)

Comment: How are validating the data is showing up (or not showing up in your case)?

Comment: I was seeing in https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/project-id/

Yesterday I didn't have any data but now It was, probably was something with cache or take some time in refresh dat

Comment: Were you looking at the table preview, or actually querying the data?

Comment: I was looking table preview, and this say that didn't have rows, but now show information
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known bug with using the table preview. You should query the table directly to see if there is data in it.

Comment: Is it so hard to fix? Its 2018 and still face the same problem.